# What accounting software exist to support crypto exchanges?

Tags: exchanges, accounting

I've been looking at QuickBooks and 3rd party tools to integrate to see what they do but it still seems to be more retail focused.

I've tried to Google it but still get retail responses. Does anyone know of any accounting software that would be ideal or specifically designed for crypto exchanges? I tried asking Coinbase and BitBuy what they use but I got no response lol

This is for research purposes to try and ascertain what's available, what these tools excel at and what they lack.

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Crypto exchange services mostly use the same kind of software as the banks. Most of them use high-security coding protocols and the software based on setting the proper account base, with one exception, most of the crypto exchange services are not obliged with any government taxes because in many countries is no legal regulations about cryptocurrency operations, that's the reason why many [pay stub maker](https://www.paystubcreator.net/) services today are so popular for crypto traders if they want to pay some taxes for the government.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! It'd be great if you could expand on this answer, as it doesn't really provide any details that answer the question. For example, which software do banks use?